# How to read from the console? - Linux

Tags: linux, command

I have a scenario where I am printing something from an application to the linux CLI.  I have another application that will be reading that value from the command line.  Is there a linux command that I can execute that will read a line from the console? I am using a java application to write to the console and a asterisk box reading from the console. Thanks

Comment: When you say "from the command line", do you mean that the other application wants the value as a command-line argument, or that it wants to read it from its standard input stream?

Comment: read as a standard input stream.  I don't believe there is a way of getting the 2 applications to communicate any other way than printing something to the console and having the other application read the line from the console.

Comment: You could have one process write something to a _pipe_ and then have the other read from the read end of that pipe. It would be a rather odd unix application that refused to write to its stdout unless that stdout were actually a console (and similarly for reading and stdin).

Comment: The term to google for is "Interprocess Communication", or "IPO".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use piping, e.g:

```
cat foo.txt | wc -l
```

This allows you to redirect one process output to another process input.